# REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL not returning correct results in APACHE PIG

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to transform unstructured data into structured form. The data is of the following form - (showing 1 row of data)

```
Agra - Ahmedabad###     Sat, 24 Jan###  http://www.cleartrip.com/m/flights/results?from=AGR&to=AMD&depart_date=24/01/2015&adults=1&childs=0&infants=0&class=Economy&airline=&carrier=&intl=n&page=loaded        Air India###    15:30 -
14:35###        47h 5m, 3 stops , AI 406###     Rs. 30,336###
```

and I want to extract the data in the following format using APACHE PIG

```
(Agra - Ahmedabad,Sat, 24 Jan,http://www.cleartrip.com/m/flights/results?from=AGR&to=AMD&depart_date=24/01/2015&adults=1&childs=0&infants=0&class=Economy&airline=&carrier=&intl=n&page=loaded,Air India,15:30 - 14:35,47h 5m, 3 , AI 406 , 30,336)
```

I am using the following lines in APACHE PIG :

```
A = LOAD '/prodqueue_cleartrip_23rdJan15.txt' using PigStorage as (value: chararray);

B = foreach A generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL('value', '([^#]+)#+\\s+([^#]+)#+\\s+([^\\s]+)\\s+([^#]+)#+\\s+([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\\s-\\n[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})#+\\s+([^,]+),\\s([0-9]+)\\sstops\\s,\\s([^#]+)#+\\s+Rs.\\s([^#]+)#+
');


C = LIMIT B 5;
```

The output I am getting is this :

```
()
()
()
()
()
```

What is the mistake?

Comment: Are you trying to match this? https://regex101.com/r/ZrhUzC/1

Answer (score 0):

This may be just a typo for your question but

```
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL('value', '([^#]+)#+\\s...
```

would just search a literal "value".  You probably want to take out the single quote so that it matches the *field* value.

```
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(value, '([^#]+)#+\\s...
```